# How to find out which terminal is being configured?

Tags: configuration, serial-port, tty, termios

Assume you want to connect your Ubuntu 13.04 desktop computer via [TTL-232R-3V3](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) USB cable to the UART interface of an embedded system running an individual Linux flavor, that does not belong to a major distribution. Your own machine offers you the interface to your connection via `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Because you are using a framework for a high level language ([pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)) you know that you configure some terminal options via the C-struct [`termios`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios).

Now the question is, where is that terminal you are configuring? Is that information you send to the remote device and configure that? Or do you simply configure how the `/dev/ttyUSB0` interface is interpreted by your system? Or is there maybe even some configuration happening in the logic of the UART-to-USB converter cable? And if all 3 are possible, how would you determine which set of parameters where configured by your `termios` manipulations on `/dev/ttyUSB0`?

If it makes things easier to explain, consider the example of `LF`/`CR` handling which can contain, depending on the flags you set, either only `LF`, only `CR` or both as would be typical for windows. My question is not limited to these options only, though.

*Note:* I came to that question after I realised that I already saw some options active, that the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) declares as not available in POSIX and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the configuration options are settings for the device driver. Most of them are implemented entirely in the driver software, such as echoing, CR-to-LF translation, and raw-vs-cooked mode.

Some of them, such as modes related to RS-232 signals, might be implemented in the device hardware, and the device driver will perform the appropriate device control operations to enable those options.